# Apache downloads the php file after updating php version from 5.3.28 to 5.4.25

Tags: php, apache, debian, mod-fcgid

I am running php on Debian 6 with mod_fcgid with DotDeb packages.

Once I upgraded php to version 5.4.25, apache downloads the php files as it does not recognize the handlers. I am not updating any config files. Once I revert back to 5.3.28 it works ok. I am not able to track anything in the error logs.

The only difference is that dotdeb don't have a php build with suhosin for 5.4, but should not make a difference because the 5.3 version works even with suhosin disabled.

Any ideas how to debug this?

Comment: if you're totally stuck you could try installing apache & php from source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that with the new version Apache needs different configuration:

In the site configuration in **/etc/apache2/sites-available/{mysite}.conf** I added:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler fcgid-script
</FilesMatch>
```

And commented out this:

```
#AddHandler fcgid-script .php
#AddHandler fcgid-script .php5
```

The same thing in **/etc/apache2/mods-available/fcgid.conf**

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you may have an entry in your .htaccess file along the lines of

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php
```

or

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php54 .php
```

When using the .htaccess to tell apache which version of PHP to use it will cause this exact problem if the declared version is either non-existent on the server or is the same version of PHP that the server is already running.

Comment: it turned out that the apache fcgid configuration for php 5.4 wants SetHandler insted of AddHandler